# GPU convolution performance in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

How are the 2D / 3D convolution operations in TensorFlow implemented, as sparse matrix - dense vector multiplications? How is performance optimised for applying many filters to the same image? How is the performance optimised for applying the same filters for many images? Is there a paper that describes the performance for different ways of implementing the convolutions?

The reason I'm asking is that I have implemented and optimised many 2D and 3D (also 4D) convolvers with CUDA, and I'm thinking if I should compare their performance to TensorFlow or not.

Comment: Tensorflow does not implement convolutions. It uses the cuDNN library.

Comment: OK, but how are convolutions implemented in cuDNN?

Comment: cuDNN is closed source and heavily optimized, so I doubt any CUDA code written by a single person would outperform. TensorFlow does have a CUDA implementation, it’s just disabled by default. I haven’t dug into the code for convs in tf, but a good starting point would be here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc.

Comment: Documentation mentions GEMM (general matrix-matrix multiplication), which needs to be sparse for 3D convolutions (otherwise filter matrix will not fit in GPU memory), and for the first layer in a 3D CNN the number of channels is 1 in medical imaging (grayscale) and the number of volumes in a batch needs to be low in 3D to fit GPU memory, so this probably results in Nf sparse matrix dense vector multiplications, where Nf is the number of filters. Should be possible to do this more efficient.